# Why is General Zod more powerful than Jor-El in "Man of Steel"?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel

In the movie *Man of Steel*, General Zod is shown as being more powerful than Jor-El, father of Superman.

Why is General Zod more powerful than Jor-El in *Man of Steel*?

Comment: Erm, because one's a solider and one's a scientist...

Comment: he gtl's every day (gym tan laundry) while jor-el grabes that popcorn and watches netflix.

Comment: I could even disagree with the assessment of being more powerful. If we're referring to the fight right before Kal-El was launched, Jor-El basically won then Zod stabbed him when he wasn't looking. Or are we talking political power?

Comment: Could you clarify "more powerful", please?

Answer (score 13):

- Zod is a soldier with big muscles.
- Jor-El is a scientist with smaller muscles.

You'll find, even on Earth, a range of strength levels in individual people.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that in Man of Steel Kryptonians are not born, but "engineered". Every individual is created to fit in a different caste, to cover the needs of Kryptonian society.

> General Zod: [Then] join me. Help me save our race. We'll start anew. We'll sever the degenerative bloodlines that led us to this state.
>
> Jor-El: And who will decide which bloodlines survive, Zod?... You?

Meant to be a soldier (and maybe a leader among soldiers) Zod should be better prepared for combat and military tactics than people who fit other roles (such as scientists). As a leader or high rank in the army he has troops under his command, who follow him for his rebellion (If Jor-El has somebody under his command, odds are that they would be scientist or researchers too, maybe even just drones, so his "retinue" could not match Zod's).

Comment: On Earth people aren't engineered, but I'd put my money on the soldier just the same. In fact, this doesn't answer the question so much as it raises the question of why Kryptonian scientists aren't engineered with excellent brains *and*  physiques that are just a good as a soldier's.